# How create a global function to initiallize all UI widgets in android

Tags: android, android-widget, findviewbyid

I am new to android . My application contains several activities and each activity view contains several widgets. So at onCreate callback I am initiallizing all widgets like `(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_id)` and this is required in almost all activities and it is lengthy too. Since it is more like a common process in all activities , is it possible to create a function globally to perform this widget initiallization , and call this from activities with corresponding layout?

Answer (score 3):

If all this widget have similar name, you can create BaseActivity class and replace all this thinks in onCreate of BaseActivity.

If all this widget different, you can try to use [AndroidAnnotation](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki)

For example, if you want to inject some view in your activity:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

   @ViewById(R.id.txt_id)
   TextView text; //Must be default, protected or public

   @AfterViews
   void initViews() {
   //Start point, where you can use injected Views, NOT IN onCreate();
   text.setText("Some text");
}}
```